# Disable system property logging in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am running Jmeter using `java -jar jmeter.jar ...` command and passing a bunch of system properties using `-D` option. I see that the system properties are being printed in the jmeter log file. I want to avoid that. Is it possible to suppress printing these system properties in Jmeter? I want to avoid printing these because I am passing API key to the Jmeter file.

Sample jmeter.log file contents:

```
2022-05-09 10:00:00,213 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting System property: API_KEY=API_KEY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like command-line arguments you can set the logging level for [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.html) class to something less verbose via `-L` command-line option:

```
java -jar jmeter.jar -Lorg.apache.jmeter.JMeter=WARN
```

In order to make change permanent and won't have to set the above override each time you launch JMeter add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.JMeter" level="warn" />
```

More information:

- [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)